# Any plugins that upload, resize, and display images?

Tags: plugins, images, gallery, plugin-recommendation

Here is an ideal workflow for my situation:

1. Upload a folder full of images
2. Resize images according to a specified size
3. Have the ability to organize these images into folders (collection1, collection2, etc)
4. Display the images within these folders in a non-flash gallery (collection1 on page 1, collection2 on page 2, etc)

Is there any plugin that will help this process from start to finish, or set of plugins that play nicely together?

It's important that these galleries work on non-flash-supported devices, as mobile and tablet traffic will be significant.

Paid is fine for a good quality plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've been using [nextgen gallery](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/) and i believe it fits your needs:

*1. Upload a folder full of images* : **yes**

*2. Resize images according to a specified size* : **yes**, on the gallery option you can set the standard size.

*3. Have the ability to organize these images into folders (collection1, collection2, etc)* : **yes**,  they're called albums and galleries. Albums contain Galleries, and each Gallery  can a set of images.

*4. Display the images within these folders in a non-flash gallery (collection1 on page 1, collection2 on page 2, etc)* : **yes** use the shortcode `[nggallery id="x"]`

there's also many plugins that extend it's funcionaly, like extra slideshows and lightbox effects.